# extract string from edittext to textview in one activity android

Tags: android

i will extract sting from editText to TextView,, but i have problem,,,
this my code :

```
public class M_bab4_a1_panc extends Activity {
String s1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.m_bab4_a1_panc);

    final EditText et;
    final Button b;
    final TextView tv;


    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ok1);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t1);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bok1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            s1 = (String) et.getText().toString();
            tv.setText(getBaseContext().getString(R.id.ok1));
        }
    });
  }
}
```

but output is "false"

can anyone help me solve this problem??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use this one..

```
 s1 = et.getText().toString();
 tv.setText(s1);
```

and if you want to get from string.xml then use

```
 tv.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.ok1));
```

**NOTE:** Remember one thing when you extract value from ***EditText*** or ***TextView*** and take that value in String then you have to just set that ***String*** to ***TextView***.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this to set text on Textview -

```
s1 = et.getText().toString();
tv.setText(s1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You store the value of the `EditText` view in the string variable `s1`.

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        s1 = (String) et.getText().toString();
        tv.setText(getBaseContext().getString(R.id.ok1));
    }
```

So just insert it, like so:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        s1 = (String) et.getText().toString();
        tv.setText(s1);
    }
```

The reason you get `false` is because you are trying to get a string resource which does not exist.